# How to highlight all occurrences of string in notepad++ user defined language by defining it as keyword?

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

Can we define in Notepad++ user defined language a keyword which  if contained in any string will be highlighted automatically?

eg. keyword in defined in language
Actual file should highlight like
discont**in**uation
sisk**in**
ma**in** theme

I understand I can highlight prefix but is there a way to highlight inside of string or ending string as well?
In programming language can we highlight the string inside word which 'contains' the desired string?

Comment: Is it not possible as we can not tokanize? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this issue which is not through user defiened langauage but a Notepad++ functionality.
I can goto find, switch to mark tab and enter the keyword and click on mark all as shwon below
[image]

But this is workaround for me which might work for many people.

Is there something else we can do in custom languages as well?